# Custom fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have developed an custom adapter which takes data from SQLite. Data is selecting and adapter also gets data. I printed data get in the adapter . 
I want to make the listview indexable and add the fast scroll.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ouvagedisplay_list);
    if (findViewById(R.id.ouvagedisplay_detail_container) != null) {             
        mTwoPane = true;
        ((OuvageDisplayListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.ouvagedisplay_list))
                .setActivateOnItemClick(true);
    }

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    db = new MySQLiteHelper(getActivity());
    initList();
    SimpeAdapterOuvrages = new SimpeAdapterOuvrages(list,getActivity());
    setListAdapter(SimpeAdapterOuvrages);
}
```

**activity_ouvagedisplay_list.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:showDividers="middle"
tools:context=".OuvageDisplayListActivity" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/ouvagedisplay_list"
    android:name="fr.artinove.OuvageDisplayListFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ouvagedisplay_detail_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="3" />
```

Comment: I don't know clear your question. Question Title and describe not match and which is your point of question.

Comment: I wanna just add a scroll indexable in the fragments List

Comment: what is the issue with using indexable List ??

Comment: In the simple blank activity i use a listview  and the code like this to implements the indexable scroll :
listViewIndexable = (IndexableListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewIndexable);
  
  simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapterCustom(list, this);
  listViewIndexable.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
  listViewIndexable.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
  listViewIndexable.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
 but in the master details flow activity how to make it

Comment: dint get you **but in the master details flow activity how to make it** ??